# my device is visible in fastboot devices but when i try to flash a custom recovery it always fails

Tags: android, fastboot

so my devices (Asus [zenfone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYft9.png) max pro m1 X00TD) boot-loader was already unlocked but today when I was testing a ROM (android 11 ) it not only didn't boot but also made the custom shop recovery (based on TWRP ) disappear and after doing the regular 2 buttons in my case vol(-)and power button it was stuck at the Asus logo and after a lot of time, it booted into the AOSP recovery but also had errors saying almost all file directories were missing .and hence I tried to use the fast boot to reflash TWRP recovery but every time I did so the shell was either stuck or said many errors (screenshots are given ) any help will be nice. plus I still am a novice at this.

Comment: Which rom were you trying? and what command did you use to flash rom? you can also boot a recovery without flashing one by ```fastboot boot recovery.img```

Comment: I see thanks for that . I was actually testing the stock aosp 11 while this happened . And for flashing I used the command fastboot flash recovery and then the recoveries directory . Fyi was able to fix the issue seems to be a windows 10 issue as I tried the same in windows 7 with no issues and also tried using another android phone for finishing it .

Answer (score 0):

Ok after lots of methods as what in the end worked for me was using an app called bugjaeger . I installed it in another phone where the debugging was enabled in developers options and with a usb org adapter and a cable I connected it to my nom functional device where I flashed and later booted using the commands
fastboot flash recovery (then giving it tbe recoveries directory ) and then fastboot boot recovery (again giving the path files )